# Android project not showing in launcher

Tags: java, android, input, emulation

I have just created a project in Android Studio.
Here's the manifest:    '

```
android:allowBackup="true"android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
</application>
```

My app is not running on start. What do i do?
I can find my app under apps, but I can't open it, althought it says it's running. I want to have an icon for it on the home screen. All I have right now is some ui input.

Manifest.xml

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: Have a look at this: http://developer.android.com/training/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the intent filters for you launching activity in your `androidmanifest.xml` ?

```
<activity android:name="MainActivity">
    <!-- This activity is the main entry, should appear in app launcher -->
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```